# Locate control in asp:listview when I have the clientid for the control?

Tags: c#, listview, webforms

- VS2012, .NET 4.51, WebForms

From a click event in the code behind I have the client ID for a control within the ItemTemplate (naturally said control is created for each of the records within the listview):

```
var lastControlWithFocusClientId = "cphContainer_ucTakeTest_lvData_txtAnswer_0";
```

I need to find that control so I tried:

```
lvData.FindControl(lastControlWithFocusClientId)
```

and

```
Page.FindControl(lastControlWithFocusClientId)
```

However both return null (ie control not found.) So what am I missing here?

**EDIT** ListView markup added:

```
<asp:ListView runat="server"
                            ID="lvData"
                            ItemType="MyItemType"
                            SelectMethod="GetQuestions"
                            OnItemDataBound="lvData_OnItemDataBound"  OnItemCreated="lvData_ItemCreated">
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <tr>
                                    <td><span class="label label-info"><%#: Item.QuestionNumber %></span></td>
                                    <td>
                                        <asp:Label ID="lblQuestionText" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("QuestionText") %>' />
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <img src='/ImageHandler.ashx?questionNo=<%#: Item.QuestionNumber %>'>
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <div class="input-group">
                                            <asp:TextBox data-sessionid='<%# SessionsId %>' data-question-no='<%#: Item.QuestionNumber %>' Enabled='<%# !ShowStudentResults %>' CssClass="form-control FlyoutCandidate" ID="txtAnswer" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                                            <span data-content='<%#: GetAnswerInstructions(Item.SolutionType) %>' class="input-group-addon flyout-candidate-hint"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-comment"></span></span>
                                            <span class="input-group-addon special-character-toggle"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-credit-card"></span></span>
                                        </div>
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <img runat="server" data-sessionid='<%# SessionsId %>' data-qno='<%# Item.QuestionId %>' data-id='<%# Item.QuestionNumber %>' onclick="javascript: TakeTestJs.DisplayQuestionHelp(this); return false;" src="/Images/help-icon.png" width="32" height="32" alt="" />
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <asp:Panel runat="server" ID="imgHint"></asp:Panel>
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <asp:Label CssClass="label label-info" ID="lblStudentMark" runat="server" Text='<%# Item.StudentMark %>' />
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <asp:Label CssClass="label label-primary" ID="lblOutOf" runat="server" Text='<%# Item.QuestionOutOf %>' />
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <asp:Label ID="lblSolutionText" runat="server" Text='<%# Item.SolutionText %>' />
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:ListView>
```

Comment: Have added the listview markup

Comment: in which event you want to find control?

Comment: @Damith  In a button click event in the code behind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up implementing the following recursive search as @user2930100 did not work for me:

```
    private Control RecursiveFindControl(Control aRootControl, string aFindControlClientId)
    {
        if (aRootControl.ClientID == aFindControlClientId)

            return aRootControl;

        foreach (Control ctl in aRootControl.Controls)
        {
            Control foundControl = RecursiveFindControl(ctl, aFindControlClientId);

            if (foundControl != null)
                return foundControl;
        }

        return null;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

findcontrol is not recursive, so you have to do a bit of workaround. Here is my code, modified version of what I got from somehwere around here:

```
private Control RecursiveFindControl(Control targetControl, string findControlId) {
if (targetControl.HasControls()) {
    foreach (Control childControl in targetControl.Controls) {
        if (childControl.ID == findControlId) {
            return childControl;
        }

        RecursiveFindControl(childControl, findControlId);
    }
}

return null;}
```

just use:

```
RecursiveFindControl(this, ControlName)
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using .NET4 and higher, you can actually set the ClientMode property and set this yourself so you don't even have to work with the confusing ClientIDs that are generated by ASP.NET and nested server controls.

Check out this MSDN article for the `ClientIDMode` property

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.clientidmode%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Otherwise, to maybe more accurately answer your question, you can't do a FindControl on the controls collection itself because it will fail.

Typically when I work with a ListView, I end up taking the control that triggers the event for that row.

So if I have a LinkButton in the row, and I have a click event, I will do the following

```
protected void btnConfirm_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    LinkButton btn = (LinkButton)sender;
    ListViewDataItem row = btn.NamingContainer as ListViewDataItem;

    if (row != null)
    {
        HiddenField hiddenFieldWithSomething = row.FindControl("hiddenControl") as HiddenField;
        //var lastControlWithFocusClientId = cphContainer_ucTakeTest_lvData_txtAnswer_0";
        if (hiddenFieldWithSomething.ClientID == lastControlWithFocusClientId) 
        {
            //Do something here
        }
    }
}
```

When doing it this way, it's a little more fine-tuned and you still go through your typical event handler.

The RecursiveFindControl helper that was posted in this question will give you a much more robust and reusable solution.